# YouTube Twitter Social Media Icon Bug

Tags: twitter, hyperlink, youtube, favicon

**PROBLEM**

The standard URL format for including Twitter account links on YouTube pages does not render the favicon properly for some users. The picture below shows how a globe is put in place of where the Twitter logo is supposed to go.

```
http://twitter.com/gregdegruy
```

[image]

Comment: you can use fa fa class

Comment: http://fontawesome.io/icon/twitter/, scalable, but I do not see how I can replace with the default twitter icon in youtube links.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Just add `/#!` to your Twitter URL like I've done below and your favicon should render correctly from then on :).

```
http://twitter.com/#!/gregdegruy
```

[image]